# Why can't i run my flutter app in vs code terminal/cmd if my previous apps went on android studio?

Tags: flutter

When i type "flutter run" in folder of my app created in VS CODE or cmd i get this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on LG H870 in debug mode...
Target file "C:\Users\Kwiat\Documents\\Users\Kwiat\Documents\\Users\Kwiat\Documents\Projects\Flutter\kaka\kaka\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\android-arm64/flutter_assets" not found.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 765

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebugArm64'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Why i haven't got flutter_assets file and Target file path is so weird? How to fix it to run my apps?

Comment: Do you mean to say you could run the same app using android studio but you can't run it using the vscode+ terminal?

Comment: @Doc Nah, i can run app which i created in android studio, but i can't run app created in cmd with flutter create command.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i just realised that flutter doesn't support foldernames with'!' in it. I tried to create project in folder without '!' and it worked.